# Upgrade SQL Server 2008 to 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2, upgrade

I have currently installed SQL Server 2008 (dev edition) in my machine. I wish to upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2. How is that possible?

Please support the same with screenshot to make understanding better.

Thanks

**EDIT**: I could have gone for Google Search but the attached screenshot provides no option to upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2 Edition (Attached Screenshot is of SQL Server 2008 Dev Edition). Please see the text written under "Upgrade from.... 2005"

[image: Please see image desc]

Comment: Any comments Naveed you wish to add?

Comment: See the product name down on the left hand side of the dialogue box. That's the SQL 2008 installer, not the 2008R2 installer. That's why there's no `"Upgrade from SQL Server 2000, SQL Server 2005 or SQL Server 2008"` option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The option should appear in the "SQL Server Installation Center" as confirmed by the following screenshot and point 4 of the Microsoft guide on [How to Upgrade to SQL Server 2008 R2 (Setup)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144267.aspx)

[image]

As a side note, have you checked your intended upgrade path is supported? You can find out [here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143393.aspx)